# Pandas - how to write data to_json as [{},{}]

Tags: python, pandas

I have .ods file with structure as follow:

[image]

I read this file with pandas_ods_reader:

```
df = pandas_ods_reader.read_ods('competences.ods', 0, headers=True)
```

Then I'm using pandas .to_json method as follow:

```
df.to_json('competences.json', orient='records', lines=True, force_ascii=False)
```

What I want to achieve is to have json file like that:

```
[
   {category=102, competence="Skill", status=0},
   {...},
   {...}
]
```

but what i get is:

```
{category=102, competence="Skill", status=0}
{...}
{...}
```

Does anyone know how to achieve so?

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
df.to_json(orient='records', force_ascii=False)
```

The `lines=True` parameter removes the root-level square brackets (as is generally the standard for newline-delimited JSON files).